# Book where a girl discovers that her world is actually just an island and she goes over the cliffs to see what’s beyond

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, childrens-novel

Okay, so this book pops into my mind every once in a while, torments me with vague memories that aren’t enough to identify the book, and then leaves my mind for another couple years.

I read it in elementary school, so it has to have been written in 2007 or before. It’s a fantasy novel. I was a good reader, so it could be a YA novel or it could be meant for kids. I’m guessing it’s similar to *Gregor the Overlander* in reading level.

Disclaimer: I only remember bits of the plot, and I’m not 100% sure if what I do remember is actually correct.

The main character is a girl (a child) who lives in a time/place without modern electronics, maybe even without electricity at all. Everyone in this place believes that this place is the whole world, and the edge or perimeter of their world are cliffs that fall down into a thick fog, so they can’t tell what’s at the bottom of the cliffs. People who go over the side never come back to their world. Side note, I want to say there’s a prince in this little world, but I’m really uncertain of that.

Eventually, the girl goes over the side to see what’s beyond, and it ends up being water at the bottom of the cliffs, so their world is actually an island. She also finds a man who’s been missing a very long time, and he has boat that he’s just paddling around in. I guess either he couldn’t find his way back to the world or he didn’t want to.

The book itself was a small, but decently thick hardcover. I think I remember it being a deep red with ornate, yellow or gold decorations on the front.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! It’s driving me crazy that I can’t find it!

Comment: FWIW, I poked through https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheWallAroundTheWorld and https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SmallSecludedWorld and didn't find anything that sounded likely.